# radio button in joomla 2.5 registration form

Tags: radio-button, joomla2.5, registration

I've made a user profile plugin for Joomla 2.5 using this tutorial [link](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/user-profile/copy-user-profile-plugin)

It works great, but I need the custom field that I added to be a radio button instead of text, because it's a "male/female' option.

Here is how it looks like in /plugins/user/profile10/profiles/profile.xml:

```
            <field
            name="gender"
            type="text"
            id="gender"
            description="Male or Female?"
            filter="string"
            label="Male or Female?"
            message="PLG_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_WEB_SITE_MESSAGE"
            size="30"
        />
```

and plugins/user/profile10/profile10.xml:

```
<field name="register-require_gender" type="list"

                description="Your gender"
                label="Male or female?"
            >
                <option value="2">JOPTION_REQUIRED</option>
                <option value="1">JOPTION_OPTIONAL</option>
                <option value="0">JDISABLED</option>
</field>
```

I noticed the line ***type="text"*** but I'm not sure what I replace it for and where I place both options.

Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Joomla documentation for [Standard Form Field Types](http://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_types), you want to use the [Radio](http://docs.joomla.org/Radio_form_field_type) type. In this case, type would be 'radio' and you would add options for each value specified.

Comment: Thank you so  much! I couldn't find it in google before, I guess I searched with the wrong words. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is the code that I've used:

```
<field
  name="gender"
  type="radio"
  id="gender"
  label="PLG_USER_TESTPROFILE_FIELD_GENDER_LABEL"
  default="m">
  <option value="m">Male</option>
  <option value="f">Female</option>
</field>
```